# Python CSV, elements remain on same cell in txt file

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

So I'm trying to create several columns for information, and I'm naming the columns, or the labels in top of the columns, but the code writes them in the following way:

```
Name,Age,Height,Weight,Budget,Objective,Type of diet
```

And all of this in one single cell, and I want them to be each in a different column. The code is the following:

```
import csv

fields = ["Name","Age", "Height", "Weight", "Budget", "Objective",  '''Type of diet''']
filename = "nutritec.csv"

with open(filename, 'w+') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: If I run your code exactly as is I get each field in a separate column when opened in Excel - What version of Python are you using and what are you using to open the csv file to check it?

Comment: I have no idea which version of python I have, and I open the document with Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some time, i found how that the problem happes due to Windows configuration. I solved it changing the "," deep into windows configuration.

1. Go to Windows Settings
2. Go to Time and Language
3. Additional Options of Date, Time and Regional Settings
4. Change date, time and number formats
5. Additional Settings
6. Change "List separator" by a ,

Sorry if the words are wrong, not natal language and windows is in different language

Answer (score 1):

Running your code I get the following output:

```
Name,Age,Height,Weight,Budget,Objective,Type of diet
```

This is the correct output for a CSV Header row. According to [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2):

> There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line
> of the file with the same format as normal record lines.  This
> header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file
> and should contain the same number of fields as the records in
> the rest of the file (the presence or absence of the header line
> should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this
> MIME type).  For example:

> 

field_name,field_name,field_name CRLF
aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the (locale) settings, Excel can use a different separator as default when opening a file (for example `,`, `;` or maybe `<tab>`).

You can force Excel to use comma like this:

```
sep=,
Name,Age,Height,Weight,Budget,Objective,Type of diet
```

This is 'Excel specific', but most other csv readers should recognize or ignore this first line.

Another option is to use a different separator.

You could also import the csv file instead of just opening the file. This gives you the chance to select the separator and some other settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you are using excel (or any other spreadsheets) to open your csv file. 
All the csv you will open in excel will use one single cells for each line since the usage of "columns" doesn't exist in csv.

You should try using xlsxwriter or something similar to produce a xlsx file

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using Excel, I will look for xlswriter

Answer (score 0):

CSV means the values are Comma-separated and hence when you view it in excel you will see it all in 1 column. You can set the delimiter in excel to "," and it should seperate all the fields into different columns. 
Alternatively you could use the xlwt module to write to excel.

```
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1') 

for i in range(len(fields)):
 sheet1.write(0, i, fields[i])
```

You could also use pandas but that seems a tad excessive.

Comment: thank you for the answer!, however I'm supposed to use csv, and I have executed codes like this on other computers and I get the correct output, which leads me to believe its the computer or something related with my excel. Nevertheless thanks for responding.